# mysql-connector-java for mysql 5.6

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

I have a project in play! framework. I used mysql 5.1 and added mysql-connector-java dependencies and it worked pretty well.

But now I need to upgrade mysql to 5.6, yet there is no mysql-connector-java for 5.6 that I can find.

Can anyone provide some walk-around in this case? Is it possible to have 2 versions of mysql where one for the project and one for my other need such as integration with the db backup, while the two version  shares the same db?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: just use the old version, it is compatible!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-versions.html it says that for MySQL 4.1, 5.0, 5.1, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7 recommended Connector/J version is 5.1

Comment: The above url is not valid currently.

Comment: Latest Url : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html
Download Link (Maven) : http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar

Comment: download from here http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.jar.zip

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti the URL doesnt specify that it supports MySQL server of 5.5 and earlier versions on that link. Should I still proceed to use connector/j 5.1 for MySQL server version of 5.1.73?